# Need to calculate the number of possible model codes

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate the number of possible pizza combinations I can make at my pizza shop. We offer 5 toppings: Pepperoni, Sausage, Peppers, Onions, and Ham. Customers may specify which toppings they want(if any) and they may order a regular, double, or triple amount of individual toppings. If I were to break pizzas down in to model codes for simplification, I could break it down in to a five character code with each character representing the unique topping and the character value representing amount of that specific topping. For example:

Cheese Pizza = 00000;
Pepperoni Pizza = 10000;
Sausage and Triple Onion Pizza = 01030

I understand I can calculate all of the possible combinations(00000-33333) by doing this:

$4^5 = 1024$

However we do not allow the sum of the characters to equal more that 6. This is kind of where I am lost on the math. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please share what you have tried!

Comment: Hello. Thank you for replying. I am not sure where to start with this type of problem. I was unable to search for a similar solution due to the fact that I do not really know how to word what I am asking for.

Comment: What I ended up doing was making an Excel sheet and counted columns A1:A9999 with sequential numbers. Then in the B column I wrote a formula that added all the numbers in the corresponding A column. This way each cell in the B column would be assigned a number from 0 to 45. Then in the C column I did an IF statement that would assign the cell a 1 if the value in the corresponding B column was less than 7 and a 0 if it was greater than or equal to 7. I then did a summation of the C column.